# How can I prevent Windows from automatically deleting malicious files?

Tags: anti-virus, windows-10

I am working on a presentation and want to copy an old exploit code [(github-file)](https://github.com/CCrashBandicot/helpful/blob/master/CVE-2010-0249.py) to a file in Sublime3 with nice syntax, highlighting, and so on.

But when I try to save the file, Windows automatically detects the malicious content and deletes it within seconds.

Is there a way to prevent such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable Windows Defender to prevent the behavior, don't do it on your system, use instead a development Windows 10 virtual machine to develop your exploit.

[Disable Windows Defender](https://www.wikihow.com/Turn-Off-Windows-Defender-in-Windows-10)

[Download Windows 10 vm](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/)

Comment: Disabling it is only temporary, windows will enable it after a period of time.